# Property values empty in this.props

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have the following Component that I want to render (
https://github.com/sbycrosz/react-native-credit-card-input/blob/master/src/CreditCardInput.js). Its working fine however I want to assign default card field values e.g. number, using the `values` props defined.

```
<CreditCardInput
    gooble={{number: 4111111111111111}}
    values={{number: 4111111111111111}}
    requiresName
    requiresCVC
    requiresPostalCode
    validatePostalCode={validatePostalCode}
    cardImageFront={cardFront}
    cardImageBack={cardBack}
    labelStyle={addCardStyle.label}
    inputStyle={addCardStyle.input}
    validColor={"black"}
    invalidColor={"red"}
    placeholderColor={"darkgray"}
    onFocus={this._onFocus}
    onChange={this._onChange.bind(this)}/>
```

The actual **CreditCardInput.js** file should deconstruct these values and pre-populated the fields according to the source code in the link above:

```
const {
  cardImageFront, cardImageBack, inputContainerStyle,
  values: { number, expiry, cvc, name, type }, focused,
  allowScroll, requiresName, requiresCVC, requiresPostalCode,
  cardScale, cardFontFamily, cardBrandIcons,
} = this.props;

    <CreditCard 
     ...
     number={number}
     ...
```

However when i debug on **CreditCardInput.js** during render I can see that the this.props contains `values` property, however this is an empty object (instead of containing the number value defined). This seems very odd behaviour. I have tested with other props passed through (E.g: `gooble={{number: 4111111111111111}}`) and it is populated correctly in this.props even though its exactly the same, except for the names.

So in CreditCardInput.js when I change the source code from above to using the prop `gooble` it works:

```
const {
  cardImageFront, cardImageBack, inputContainerStyle,
  gooble: { number, expiry, cvc, name, type }, focused,
  allowScroll, requiresName, requiresCVC, requiresPostalCode,
  cardScale, cardFontFamily, cardBrandIcons,
} = this.props;

    <CreditCard 
     ...
     number={number}
     ...
```

However why isnt it working with `this.props.values`/ why is `this.props.values` an empty object.

Comment: Are you passing these props from store ?

Comment: I want to eventually. But for now I was just using the method described in my question.